# Mudança de data de uma média mensal do Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá. Usando o código abaixo eu realizo uma média mensal, porém ela fica fixada no último dia do mês corrente e eu gostaria de saber se é possível configurar ela para um dia fixo do mês como o dia primeiro ou o dia 15 por exemplo.

No código, `123456789.csv` é um arquivo genérico com dados diários durante alguns anos dos quais serão tirados as médias mensais e o `index_col` está fixando a data como índice.

```
file0 = pd.read_csv('123456789.csv', sep = ',', index_col = 0)
file0.index = pd.to_datetime(file0.index)
monthly_mean = file0.resample('M').mean()
```

Esse seria um exemplo do output original:

```
                  Dados
Data                      
2006-01-31        4.206452
2006-02-28        3.878571
2006-03-31        4.038710
2006-04-30        4.113333
2006-05-31        4.306452
...                    ...
2014-08-31        4.312903
2014-09-30        4.456667
2014-10-31        3.958065
2014-11-30        3.950000
2014-12-31        3.661290
```

E esse seria um exemplo de resultado:

```
                  Dados
Data                      
2006-01-15        4.206452
2006-02-15        3.878571
2006-03-15        4.038710
2006-04-15        4.113333
2006-05-15        4.306452
...                    ...
2014-08-15        4.312903
2014-09-15        4.456667
2014-10-15        3.958065
2014-11-15        3.950000
2014-12-15        3.661290
```

Comment: Você pode disponibilizar o arquivo `123456789.csv` ou um exemplo equivalente?

Comment: Essa é uma questão bastante pertinente. A partir da versão 1.1 do pandas, existe uma opção de `offset` e uma de `origin` no `DataFrame.resample`, mas nenhuma delas parece funcionar para mês. A solução que eu consegui pensar é subtrair 15 dias da data, fazer o resample e corrigir a data no output do resample. Mas joguei uma pergunta no stack em inglês pra ver se alguém da uma sugestão melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, existem duas soluções pro seu problema ,mas só uma eu achei adequada. Ela consiste em fazer um offset falso no seu DataFrame em que se subtrai 14 dias de todas as datas, calcula-se a média mensal e depois soma-se 14 dias nos labels:

```
df['offset'] = df.index - pd.Timedelta('14D')
monthly_mean = df.resample('M', on='offset').mean()
monthly_mean.index = monthly_mean.index + pd.Timedelta('14D')
print(monthly_mean)
```

Só chamando a atenção, o programa vai imprimir dia 14 ao invés do 15, pq ele imprime a data em que o intervalo acaba, ou seja, do dia 15 do mês anterior até o dia 14 desse mês.

A outra solução consiste em dividir o período em semiperíodos usando 'SM' ao invés de 'M', mas depois precisa de uma série de manipulações para somar os valores de cada período e calcular a média. Parece simples, mas precisa ser feito com cuidado para não ter erro do intervalo que você está considerando, porque quando se usa o 'SM' ele diz o ínicio do período ao invés do fim.

Answer (score 0):

Se a questão é somente mudar o dia sem alterar a média, você pode utilizar o apply com o método replace:

```
df['data'] = df['data'].apply(lambda d: d.replace(day = 15))
```

Entrada:

```
          data     media
0   2006-01-31  4.206452
1   2006-02-28  3.878571
2   2006-03-31  4.038710
3   2006-04-30  4.113333
4   2006-05-31  4.306452
5   2014-08-31  4.312903
6   2014-09-30  4.456667
7   2014-10-31  3.958065
8   2014-11-30  3.950000
9   2014-12-31  3.661290
```

Saída

```
          data     media
0   2006-01-15  4.206452
1   2006-02-15  3.878571
2   2006-03-15  4.038710
3   2006-04-15  4.113333
4   2006-05-15  4.306452
5   2014-08-15  4.312903
6   2014-09-15  4.456667
7   2014-10-15  3.958065
8   2014-11-15  3.950000
9   2014-12-15  3.661290
```